# Avoid memory leaks in dojo?

Tags: javascript, dojo

For long running applications in the browser using a toolkit such as dojo, I hear the point over and over again that dangling references must be avoided.  But each language/framework has its own idiosyncrasies when it comes to memory management.

How can I avoid dangling references when building an app in dojo?  I'm thinking of rules along the lines of "alloc" in iOS: how to use, and how to clean up after yourself when done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the biggest thing which comes to dojo is that you should remember to disconnect any events you connect.

There's a simple pattern to this, for example in a custom dijit:

```
//connecting some events
this._events = [
    dojo.connect(...),
    dojo.connect(...)
];
```

Now, it's very straightforward to disconnect:

```
dojo.forEach(this._events, dojo.disconnect, dojo);
```

The same pattern applies when using `this.connect` in a dijit.

Comment: Note that dijit widgets automatically clean up anything connected with `widget.connect` when they are destroyed - and generally, all widgets are destroyed when the page unloads (at least in IE, which historically is where it has been shown to matter).

Answer (score 1):

It should also be noted that even if you follow the good practice of disconnecting event handlers mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7446188/avoid-memory-leaks-in-dojo/7449687#7449687), you might end up in trouble. There might be cyclic references that garbage collector is not capable to detect, or references that are not released properly by Dojo itself. Sometimes you need to explicitly call "delete" on them. See [this](http://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/11329) as an example.

Comment: I think that's the case with any toolset.  But most have some guidelines that can help with a lot of preventable situations.